# Bootstrap Navbar fixed width, but dropdown-menu width 100%

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3.0 and I want to create a Navbar menu with fixed and under it an dropdown-menu width 100% of the Full screen.

See screen how it have to be:
[image]

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 0):

Use in css as

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */.nav { margin-bottom: 0; }
.nav > li.dropdown.open { position: static; }
.nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {display:table; width: 100%; text-align: center; left:0; right:0; }
.dropdown-menu>li { display: table-cell; }
```

or link may it help you http://www.bootply.com/8EgGsi4F7w

Comment: Thanks, I have already seen such an example, In my case the navbar div have not 100% of the screen width (See my update image)

Answer (score 0):

The reason your navbar is not spanning 100% of the screen is because you have the `container` class on it, which only uses 1170px at XL, 970px at LG and 750 at SM. Correct your HTML to be:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbat-static-top">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
        <li><a href="#">More</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```